# YII1 clistview data is empty

Tags: yii, pagination, yii1.x, yii-booster, clistview

I have a custom dropdown pagination in my project and using CListView to display the items, but it's not working correctly. Whatever the number that I select in the dropdownlist, or the page number, the content of the list is empty. I can see that the summary number is changed and correctly shown, but the list is not shown. What I am missing?

Below is the model - candidateSearch() code:

```
public function candidateSearch()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('can_id',$this->can_id);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'name ASC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Below is the controller code:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) 
    {
        Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize',(int)$_GET['pageSize']);
        unset($_GET['pageSize']);
    }

    $model = new JbMeetGreet('candidateSearch');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    $model->can_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model->created_by = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model->created_by_lvl = Yii::app()->user->user_level;

    //search function
    if(isset($_POST['JbMeetGreet']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['JbMeetGreet'];
    }

    $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Below is the index page code:

```
$pageSize = Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']); 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize',$pageSize,array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20,25=>25,30=>30),
    array('onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiListView.update('meet-greet-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})",
    'empty'=>'-- Select Page Range --','style'=>'width:100%;'));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
    'id'=>'meet-greet-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->candidateSearch(),
    'itemView'=>'_profile_list',
    'template'=>'{summary}{pager}{items}',
    'summaryText'=>'Result {start} - {end} of {count} results',
});
```

Comment: When you select a new page size from your view you get any ajax response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. I have animation in my item view page. Deleted the animation code, and data in the subsequent pages are displayed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your dropDownList into your grid (to make ajax call to work):

```php
// into your view

$pageSize = Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
$perPagina = CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize', $pageSize, array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20,25=>25,30=>30),
        array('onchange' => "$.fn.yiiGridView.update('meet-greet-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})")
    );

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
    'id'=>'meet-greet-grid',

    // add this
    'header' => $perPagina,

    'dataProvider'=>$model->candidateSearch(),
    'itemView'=>'_profile_list',
    'template'=>'{summary}{pager}{items}',
    'summaryText'=>'Result {start} - {end} of {count} results',
});
```

Comment: Hi Niac, thank you for responding. Even when I use the original pager from CListView, when I click the next button, the content is not displayed. I can see the div section is reserved, however, no content. The loading bar is appeared and loaded. Did I miss out something from the index controller?

Comment: In controller you have some filter condition `$model->can_id = Yii::app()->user->id; ...` may be user it is not login `(Yii::app()->user->id == null)`

Comment: user is logged in. The filter is ok.